# IE structural problems

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, wordpress, syntax-error

I have just made a very simple static side via wordpress. However, I made the theme from scratch with html and css. It looks perfect and exactly how I want in FFox,Chrome,Safari etc...but upon inspection in IE 6,7,8 is is not right.

Click {*[here](http://www.paradeofflesh.com)*} to see the site and if you don't have IE... Here is a screen shot of how it is rendering in there.

[image]

Any idea on what this may be or an idea on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated. I can't find any syntax errors in my css and the html seems right

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your document you don't set a DOCTYPE, so ie is forced to show it in quirks mode. You have to add the DOCTYPE in the start of your html code. You can find more information about DOCTYPE at http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Also you can find more information about quirks mode at http://www.quirksmode.org/

As last note, it's always valuable to validate your webpages using [3w validator](http://validator.w3.org/). Doing this with your website, you can see that you get :

> 93 Errors, 15 warning(s)

and the first of all in the list is the following:

> No DOCTYPE found! Checking with
>   default XHTML 1.0 Transitional
>   Document Type.
>
> No DOCTYPE Declaration could be found
>   or recognized in this document. This
>   generally means that the document is
>   not declaring its Document Type at the
>   top. It can also mean that the DOCTYPE
>   declaration contains a spelling error,
>   or that it is not using the correct
>   syntax.
>
> The document was checked using a
>   default "fallback" Document Type
>   Definition that closely resembles
>   “XHTML 1.0 Transitional”.
>
> Learn how to add a doctype to your
>   document from our FAQ.

Hope all the above information you be helpful understanding what happens with ie.

Comment: WOW! adding the doc type fixed it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: also thank you so much for introducing me to the markup validation service. That is gonna be huge in my troubleshooting future :)

Answer (score 1):

Well for one, not sure how new you are to CSS/HTML development, but this is NEVER a surprise that you create content in one browser only to have IE puke and choke and display something differently.  Its one of the crutches that web designers / developers have to carry when making projects.

You make it right, then you mod a stylesheet to be IE approved.

You need to use conditional comments to attach those IE only sheets, and you might even have to do it for IE6 / 7 / 8 seperately, depending on what you did and how it breaks the look.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Example of this usage in the `<head>`:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie6-fixes.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

You would of course have your 'default' style sheet BEFORE the ie one, and the ie.css would overwrite the initially defined styles.

Only correct way to go about it.

Comment: yeah IE is a nightmare. This makes a lot of sense, but still does not help me know WHAT to fix/mod and put in those IE approved sheets. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is usually a way to have a website render in all browsers correctly without using an IE template, but it takes a bit of work.

Try adding margin-left: auto; and margin-right: auto; and/or width:100% to your body.

Also it is good practice to wrap things that need to exist on the same y-axis, such as your tab and content in a div so that they can move together.

Comment: Let me know how this looks, it probably won't fix it outright, but it's a step in the right direction and is only redundant to the other browsers.

Comment: I tried margin-right: auto; and/or width:100% to the body in all possible combos. One of each, and all together. Did not change anything. I have just now wrapped the tabs and page content in a container div that has this css ( .container { width:960px; margin:0px auto 0px auto;} ) still whacky. I have to agree with you that the below answer does seem a little much, although I would be happy to do it if I knew what specifics to utilize to solve the problem.